# Looping through array of objects in Python coming from Javascript

Tags: javascript, python

Coming from Javascript I am trying to learn Python(very slowly). I'm trying to work out how to do a loop in Python script over an array of objects.

For example say I have the following object:

```
contacts = [{name:"John",age:30},{name:"Peter",age:20},{name:"Sarah",age:33}]
```

In javascript if I wanted to loop through the array and print to console each name I would do the following.

```
for (let i = 0; i < contacts.length; ++i) {
    console.log(contacts[i][name])
}
```

Which would print out:

```
John
Peter
Sarah
```

Furthermore if I wanted to print the last name in the the list ie Sarah I would do the following

```
console.log(contacts[contacts.length-1][name])
```

My question is how would I do this in Python?

Comment: `for contact in contacts: print(contact['name'])`

Comment: thanks for this, easier than i thought. And how would i just print the last name in the array without having to loop for through?

Comment: `contacts[-1]['name']` Python has some unique indexing and slicing operations that JS does not have that you should become familiar with. There are tons of tutorials on the web.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Teach me this language feature” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
contacts = [{"name":"John","age":30},{"name":"Peter","age":20},{"name":"Sarah","age":33}]

for i in range(len(contacts)):
    print(contacts[i]["name"])
    
for person in contacts:
    print(person["name"])
```

The second way would be considered more "Pythonic".

**EDIT - added to answer question in comment**

To access only the last record in the list, use a negative offset.

```
print(contacts[-1]["name"])
```

Comment: thanks so I assume to print hplast name would simply be print(contacts[len(contacts)-1]["name"])??

Answer (score 1):

Try using a for each loop

```
contacts = [{"name":"John","age":30},{"name":"Peter","age":20},{"name":"Sarah","age":33}]
for contact in contacts:
    print(contact["name"])
```